# What is the best way to split String in java, after every 4th an 3rd position?

Tags: java, split

**Note: My English is some thing poor**

How to split `String` in java (every 4th and 3rd position).

For example, If i have a String of characters, as:

`0110000 1100001 1001100 00110000` (without spaces, spaces are for only representations)

If, I want to split it as:

`0110 000 1100 001 1001 100 0011 000` (without spaces)

How to do that in java?

I already have tried it as follows:

```
jshell> "01100001100001100110000110000".split("(?<=\\G.{4})");
$22 ==> String[8] { "0110", "0001", "1000", "0110", "0110", "0001", "1000", "0" }
```

As shown it split it into every `4th position` not `4th position && 3rd position`.

Also, Some thing that's

```
jshell> "01100001100001100110000110000".split("(?<=\\G.{4})|(?<=\\G.{3})");
$24 ==> String[10] { "011", "000", "011", "000", "011", "001", "100", "001", "100", "00" }
```

Or

```
jshell> "01100001100001100110000110000".split("(?<=\\G.{4}|\\G.{3})");
$25 ==> String[10] { "011", "000", "011", "000", "011", "001", "100", "001", "100", "00" }
```

Tried different ways but not not solved my problem. Also on the internet nothing find solution.

My question is that's how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify the programming language. You're asking about Java, yet you are using jsshell, which is JavaScript; Totally different programming languages.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa: It's Java - the Java Shell tool (JShell) is an interactive tool for learning the Java programming language and prototyping Java code.

Comment: Yeah! Java in now extended! Like Scala (Salable Language). Java is awesome....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first break the string in substrings of length 7 and process each of these substrings by splitting it after the 4th digit:

```
String string = "01100001100001100110000110000";
String[] array = string.split("(?<=\\G.{7})");
String[] array2= new String[array.length*2];

  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    String[] temp = array[i].split("(?<=\\G.{4})");
    array2[i*2] = temp[0];
    if (temp.length > 1) {
        array2[i*2+1]= temp[1];
    }
  }
```

Of course, you might want to add some additional math to skip the last "null"

```
array2 ==> String[10] { "0110", "000", "1100", "001", "1001", "100", "0011", "000", "0", null }
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer solved my problem... After modifying some code, I solved my problem.

Comment: @user10606381 : In this case, it would be great if you could mark your question as solved by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
String a ="01100001100001100110000110000";
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList();
    while (a.length()>=3)
    {
        if(a.length()>=4)
        {
            stringList.add(a.substring(0,4));
            a=a.substring(4,a.length());
            if(a.length()>=3)
            {
                stringList.add(a.substring(0,3));
                a=a.substring(3,a.length());
            }
        }
    }
    stringList.forEach(s-> System.out.println(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

In latest Java version (e.g java 11), You can write short method as follows:

```
void btnEncryptOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
var input = "01100001100001100110000110000";
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=\\G.{7})");
for (var p : parts) {
    String[] p2 = p.split("(?<=\\G.{4})");
    System.out.print(Arrays.asList(p2)); // to print as array list
}
```

The output is:

```
[0110, 000][1100, 001][1001, 100][0011, 000][0]
```